# how to align objects in jpg and center horizontally and vertically?

Tags: imagemagick

Thank you for the kind response I am new here so again write you specifically.

Here the situation is that I have a couple of jpg images of slightly different aspect ratio and I want to achieve to make them smaller in size which is 850 by 850 and take a look pictures

https://ibb.co/pfs4ZKK https://ibb.co/0ybM2Kt https://ibb.co/qR93QF9

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand your question. There is no alignment issue if both images are the same aspect ratio, which your two dimensions seem to be. So in ImageMagick 6 using convert, that would be

```
convert large_image.jpg -resize 800x449 small_image.jpg
```

In mogrify, you should create a new directory for the output. The change directory to the one with the images. Then

```
mogrify -path path/to/new_directory -format jpg -resize 800x449 *.jpg
```

This assumes that all your input images are the same 2988x1677.

Perhaps you can post your example images to some free hosting service and put the URLs here so we can see exactly what you want.

If you are resizing to a different aspect ratio, then you should add -extent to pad the resized image out and gravity center to align in the middle.. So

```
convert large_image.jpg -resize 800x449 -background white -gravity center -extent 800x449 small_image.jpg

or

mogrify -path path/to/new_directory -format jpg -resize 800x449 -background white -gravity center -extent 800x449 *.jpg
```

See:

https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#resize
https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry
https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify